# OpsWorks Rails App Server setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am trying to spin up an OpsWorks instance with the default Rails App Server setup and I am running into the following error:

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[ensure only our unicorn version is installed by deinstalling any other version]'
================================================================================


Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - /usr/local/bin/gem


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/dependencies/libraries/current_gem_version.rb:6:in ``'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/dependencies/libraries/current_gem_version.rb:6:in `ensure_only_gem_version'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/cookbooks/unicorn/recipes/default.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
```

The following image is the only configuration I've done. I have not added any additional recipes. (there are some custom security groups, but I don't think that would cause the above error. The instance I was trying to bring up was an m3.large with the Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

[image: OpsWorks set up page]

Answer (score 0):

Sign into the server and type

```
which gem
```

or

```
whereis gem
```

see if anything is returned.